# changing hidden field in client side problem

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html, dom

I have a hidden field and I change the value just before submitting the form using Javascript. But in server side it is null or empty. Request.Form["hidAction"] is
empty.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function DoChange() 
    {
        document.getElementsByName('hidAction').value = "filter";
        alert(document.getElementsByName('hidAction').value);
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
 </script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
            <select name="lst" onchange="DoChange();">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
       </div>
       <input type="hidden" id="hidActionID" name="hidAction" value="tt" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.GetElementsByName` returns an array of elements, even if there is only one.  Why not used `document.GetElementById` and assign an ID to the hidden input?  That should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do what you're doing differently, but going with what you have you could do this, assuming that there is only one element on the page with the name attribute 'hidAction' on the page:

```
function DoChange() 
{
    document.getElementsByName('hidAction')[0].value = "filter";
    alert(document.getElementsByName('hidAction')[0].value);
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

You could also do it this way, assuming there is only one form on the page:

```
function DoChange() 
{
    document.forms[0]['hidAction'].value = "filter";
    alert(document.forms[0]['hidAction'].value);
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

When you postback, Request.Form["hidAction"] shouldn't be empty now.